# Error in sequelize database associations of nodejs and mysql

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, relational-database

```
User.hasMany(Assignment, { as: 'assignments', foreignKey: 'tutorId' });
Assignment.belongsTo(User, { as: 'tutor', foreignKey: 'tutorId' });
Assignment.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: 'students',
  through: 'studentAssignment',
  foreignKey: 'assignmentId',
});
User.belongsToMany(Assignment, {
  as: 'assignments',
  through: 'studentAssignment',
  foreignKey: 'studentId',
});

Submission.belongsTo(User, { as: 'student', foreignKey: 'studentId' });
Submission.belongsTo(Assignment, {
  as: 'assignment',
  foreignKey: 'assignmentId',
});
```

> throw new AssociationError(`You have used the alias ${options.as} in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases.`);
> ^
>
> AssociationError [SequelizeAssociationError]: You have used the alias
> assignments in two separate associations. Aliased associations must
> have unique aliases.
> at new Association (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Toddle app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\base.js:13:13)
> at new BelongsToMany (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Toddle app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\belongs-to-many.js:33:5)
> at Function.belongsToMany (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Toddle app\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:43:25)
> at Object. (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Toddle app\toddleapp.js:76:8)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

i am trying to do association then i got this error

Comment: Please show model definitions and associations.

Answer (score 0):

You named two associations using the same `assignments` alias:

```js
User.hasMany(Assignment, { as: 'assignments', foreignKey: 'tutorId' });
User.belongsToMany(Assignment, {
  as: 'assignments',
  through: 'studentAssignment',
  foreignKey: 'studentId',
});
```

Simply rename one of them:

```js
User.hasMany(Assignment, { as: 'tutorAssignments', foreignKey: 'tutorId' });
User.belongsToMany(Assignment, {
  as: 'assignments',
  through: 'studentAssignment',
  foreignKey: 'studentId',
});
```